# Bluetooth Low Energy - WriteCharacteristic() failing, can characteristic be both Write and Write Without Response?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

We are designing both a BLE device, and the mobile phone app to talk to it.  We've defined a characteristic on the BLE device that has the properties

```
<properties write_no_response="true" notify="true" read="true" write="true" indicate="true"/>
```

Yes, it's overkill, we're in very early development.

The communication is working fine when I write to a characteristic on the device, but if I switch to Write Without Response:

```
m_characteristic.WriteType = GattWriteType.NoResponse;
m_characteristic.SetValue (bytes);
m_gatt.WriteCharacteristic (m_characteristic);
```

the call to WriteCharacteristic() fails.

1) Is it "legal" to have a characteristic that does both write_no_response *and* write?

2) Is it "legal" to switch from a regular write (GattWriteType.Default) to a write_no_response?

3) Is there any way to ask the BLE library why WriteCharacteristic() failed?

Comment: Yes that is legal and works perfectly for me. Are you coding in a different language than the official Java? If you use Android studio you could debug and step the code and see exactly where in Android's source code it fails. But first you should check the properties of the characteristic through Android's API and verify that they are correct. Maybe you need to clean the Bluetooth cache if you change the properties on the peripheral side?

Comment: Just found it ... the problem was that I assumed the 'OnCharacteristicWrite' callback was associated with the ACK (the response) and so I wasn't waiting for OnCharacteristicWrite() before calling the next WriteCharacteristic().  If WriteCharacteristic() returned an error code, or there was a way to check for an error code, I might have found it sooner ...